# BigQuery atomic load on time partitioned tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

Follow up on 2012's [atomic inserts in big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511379/atomic-inserts-in-big-query).

Are BigQuery load jobs to a new partition on an existing [Ingestion-time partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) atomic?

Would the new `_PARTITIONTIME` and its records only be available and present once all records are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all load/query//copy jobs in BigQuery are atomic. The only exception is script jobs, where each query in the script is atomic.